# Misconception about evaluating limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

**Question**

Find the limit of $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ \left[\frac 1 3 (3^{\frac 1 x} + 8^{\frac 1 x} + 9^{\frac 1 x})\right]^x\ .$$

---

**My working**

I know that the limit is $6$, which can be found through exponentiation. However, I would like to know why the following method (which I tried initially) gives the wrong answer of $1$. So, I thought that, since $x \rightarrow \infty\ $, $\frac 1 x \rightarrow 0\ $. Thus, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\ \left[\frac 1 3 (3^{\frac 1 x} + 8^{\frac 1 x} + 9^{\frac 1 x})\right]^x = [\frac 1 3 (3^0 + 8^0 + 9^0)]^{\infty} = 1^\infty = 1\ $.

---

Any explanations as to why my original method is incorrect will be greatly appreciated :)

---

**Edit**

Thanks to some helpful comments/answers, I now know that $1^\infty$ is actually not $1$ but indeterminate!

Comment: A limit of the form $1^\infty$ may not tend to $1$. For example, consider $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

$ 1^\infty $ is an inderminate form.

It is equivalent to compute

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\frac 13(3^x+8^x+9^x))^{\frac 1x}$$

or, after taking logarithm,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac 1x\ln(1+\frac 13(3^x-1+8^x-1+9^x-1))$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{3x}(3^x-1+8^x-1+9^x-1)$$

Now, use the fact that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln(a)$$

The result you will find is $e^{\ln(2.3)}=6.$

Comment: I see. I thought $1$ to the power of anything would still be $1$.

Comment: @EthanMark Yes $1$ to any power is still $1$. But be careful since you are not working with absolute $1$ but something very close to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}a^x$ is $\infty$ when $a >1$; $1$ when $a=1$ and $0$ when $0<a<1$. In your question, $f(y)=\frac{1}{3}(3^y+8^y+9^y)$ (take $y=\frac{1}{x}$), $f(y)>1$ till $y \neq 0$. Hence, you can't just put $0$ in the expression.